# Self-Hosted Ghost Blog: How can I switch from development to production?

Tags: github, github-pages, ghost-blog, jamstack

I've installed the Ghost CMS locally and wrote a few blog posts. I'm pretty much ready with the blog and want to change the environment from local to production.

I've tried to run this code to push my local Ghost environment from local to production:

```sh
$ ghost install --production.
```

The Error Message:

> A System Error occurred.
>
> Message: Current directory is not empty, Ghost cannot be installed here.

Debug Information:

```
    OS: Mac OS X, v10.14.4
    Node Version: v10.16.0
    Ghost-CLI Version: 1.11.0
    Environment: production
    Command: 'ghost install --production'

2.28.0  │ running (development) │ http://localhost:2349/ │ 2349 │ local
```

I want to set the Ghost environment from development to production.

Also, I've read that a lot of people using Ghost and Github together when it comes to static sites. But how can I use Github and Ghost together with a Ghost production environment? I want to have my website files on Github and use the Ghost CMS online.

Hopefully, you can help.

Comment: More detail required. What are your directories? What's in them? What steps did you take? (All steps, not just one command)

Comment: First step was: npm install ghost-cli -g , and then ghost install local , thats really it pretty much

Comment: Not really, no; we don't even know what directory you're in. List the reproduction steps, exactly and without omission, in your question.